# Dijkstra - find destinations within budget

Tags: java, graph-algorithm, dijkstra

I was given a graph, including a start vertex, other vertices, and edges represent the costs going from one vertex to another. I need to find the set of destination vertices that I can travel to from the start vertex. The budget is a certain amount of dollars and the travel total cost should be within the budget. How can i implement the Dijkstra's algorithm to this problem? I think we usually use Dijkstra to find the shortest path between two fixed vertices before. But I am not sure how to implement Dijkstra on this budget problem. If someone can give some ideas, that really helps!

Comment: 1. Determine shortest path between start and every other vertex.  2. Price each trip.  3. determine which trips are in in budget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my undersatanding, Dijkstra's algorithm solves the [single-source shortest path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem#Single-source_shortest_paths) problem. This means that the resulting data structure is a tree rooted at the starting node. Typically, an implementation would store the minimum cost to reach each node from the starting node. In total, the set of vertices that can be reached within the budget are the ones to which the cost of the shortest path does not exceed the budget. The algorithm itself does not need to be modified; in an additional step, the nodes which can be reached within budged has to be returned as the output.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Dijkstra algorithm, you may end up with the below scenarios:

Assuming budget of 50 and the graph of 4 nodes (start, node 1, node 2, node 3)

Start Node -> node 1 (15) -> node 2 (10): so total cost is 25

Start Node -> node 3 (15): total cost is 15

So now what is your expected result? You should go to node 1 then node 2 and ignore node 3 (since you cannot return back to start then go to node 3, the return will cost 30 too). Or you should go to node 1, back to start, then go to node 3 (total cost of 45, the largest cost you can utilise)

What you need is not the shortest path covering all destinations which is Floyd-Warshall algorithm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd–Warshall_algorithm